# Trying to remove value from a JSON file

Tags: php, json, ajax, slim

I'm trying to remove value from a json file with AJAX request, it don't show any error but it don't delete the value, someone can check it? Thanks you!

Before the AJAX function (for insert the ID on the "erase"). (the function deletee(item) click the button that activate the dlt function)

JS:

```
function deletee(item) {
    var el = document.getElementById('erase');
    el.value = Checker[item].id;
    var r= confirm("Do you want delete it?")
    if (r==true) {
        document.getElementById('rmv').click()
    }

    }
```

JS AJAX:

```
        function dlt(item) {
    var iddlt = document.getElementById('erase').value;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/delete/'+ iddlt,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

}
```

php:

```
$app->get('/delete/{id}', function (array $args) {
$jsonContents = file_get_contents('data/data.json');
$id = $args['id'];
$data_array = json_decode($jsonContents, true);
foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['id'] == $id) {
        unset($data_array[$key]);
    }
}
$data_array = array_values($data_array);
file_put_contents('data/data.json', json_encode($data_array));
```

});

Comment: I don't see where you provide the id in your ajax call. Shouldn't be there a `data: { id: myId }`? try to enable error output with `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your php file

Comment: hello, I take the ID from the url for example /delete/1 the "1" will be the ID

Comment: The PHP code in your example isn't PHP: that's JavaScript, specifically jQuery.  Is this a copy/paste mistake, or is that what you actually have in your PHP file?

Comment: Its a copy paste mistake sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass ID to your function and Ajax URL :

```
function dlt(item_id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/delete' + item_id,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

Comment: It don't delete nothing :/

Comment: Hi Joanmi , i have checked your code                                                                  function dlt() {
    var iddlt = document.getElementById('erase')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/delete/'+ iddlt,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

}  please do in this way, you are passing wrong ID name in the ajax url.

Comment: Corrected and it don't work, I added more information on the post

Comment: try to print your value  var iddlt = document.getElementById('erase').value; console.log(iddlt); check whether value comes or not

Comment: It comes, because the link is correctly changed url/?delete=2

Comment: No, it dont delete nothing

Comment: Can you share details with me where it is hosted ?

Comment: Finally I solved it, the mistake was a variable on a php file, but now, it don't save the format correctly, when I delete an entry, it save the other entrys as: {"2":{"name":"Google","domain":"www.google.com","id":2}} , expected:[{"name":"Google","domain":"www.google.com","id":2}]

Comment: Great. finally, you fixed it.

Comment: Put it on your answer and I'll accept it, thanks you for all

Answer (score 0):

Add id in your URL to make your API work.

```
  function dlt() {
    var id= "it should be a valid id";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'api/delete/'+ id,
        dataType: 'json'
    });

}
```

Comment: It don't delete nothing :/ it was a problem but it didn't solved